# I can't show properly a list in Tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter, brackets

I'm making a study project, just a basic calendar, but I encountered an error, that I can't figure out. Firstly, I input the proper date, which later I append to a list. The next step is to click the button to list all events you already add, but I can't show it proper. It gets the awful brackets, that I can't get rid of. If I try the .format, unfortunately window shows only the first element of a list. Can you help me figure it out?

[image]

```py
def window2():
    print(events)
    win2 = Toplevel(root)
    win2.title("Lista wydarzeń")
    win2.geometry("300x200")
    events_label = Label(win2, text="Wydarzenia:")
    events_label.pack()
    if len(events) > 0:
        for x in events:
            events_show_label = Label(win2, text=events)
            events_show_label.pack()
    else:
        no_events_label = Label(win2, text="Nie dodano żadnego wydarzenia.")
        no_events_label.pack(pady=10)
```

I get the variables by `.get()` and add them to the list like that

```py
events.append(f"Nazwa: {title} \nData: {date} {time}\n")
```

Comment: You probably just have to use something like `.split("{}")` , the brackets are showing up because its in list format.

Comment: When doing a loop like `for x in events:`, you would normally then use `x` inside the loop, rather than `events`.

Comment: tkinter widgets require strings. You just need to convert your lists to strings before using them in a label. Python has several ways to convert lists or tuples to strings.